# trying to do a contact list AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

Tags: python

Trying to do a contact list where you can add and remove people from a .txt, i can add people but i get this line of error when i try to write out all the lines in the txt but the one i want to remove. I've seen other threads but don't understand what i should change.

Error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'

```
from model_contact import Contact
toDo = input("Add or remove contact: ")
if toDo == "add":
    name = input("Name: ")
    contactlist = open("contactlist.txt", "a")
    contactlist.write("\n" + name)
    contactlist.close()
    print(name + " is now added to the contactlist!")
elif toDo == "remove":
    name = input("Name of removal: ")
    contactlist = open("contactlist.txt", "r")
    lines = contactlist.readlines()
    contactlist.close()
    open("contactlist.txt", "w")
    for line in lines:
         if line.strip("\n") != name:
             lines.write(line)
```

Comment: You need to assign the result of `open()` to a variable, and write to that, not `lines`.

Comment: Similar to how you use the `contactlist` variable in the `if` block

Comment: Right.  "lines" is just a list of strings.  It is not a file.

Comment: As a design suggestion, you might consider reading the file into a list of lines at the very beginning, then have your operations work on that list of lines, then write out the result when everything is done.  Don't read and write over and over.

Comment: And learn to use the `with` statement when operating with files.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I can see why it does not make sense. Will definetly start using 'with' statement and look into my design. Thanks boys

Answer (score 0):

Just to sum up all the comments from above in a code snippet :

```
from model_contact import Contact
toDo = input("Add or remove contact: ")
name = input("Name: ") 
if toDo == "add":
    with open("contactlist.txt", "a") as contactlist:
        contactlist.write("\n" + name)
        print(name + " is now added to the contactlist!")
elif toDo == "remove":
    with open("contactlist.txt", "r") as contactlist:
        lines = contactlist.readlines()
        
    with open("contactlist.txt", "w") as ncl: #cnl == new contact list 
        for line in lines: # lines here are the read lines from above
             if line.strip("\n") != name:
                 ncl.write(line)
```

This code is very direct and has a serious flaw, which is the the second opening of the file, which if it is a big one, could be a problem.

To reduce the impact if the file is big, i would try this:

```
    with open("contactlist.txt", "r+") as contactlist:
        lines = contactlist.readlines()
        tmp = []
        
        for num, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.strip("\n") == name:
                tmp.append(num)

        for num in tmp:
            lines.pop(num)

        contactlist.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: hey thanks for the sum in code with the 'with' statements. Will look more into the second code when i've leveled up

Comment: just a quick question, if i were to add emails to the list(self.email=email) could i still use the same strategy with deleting, just given the name and it would delete the entire name and email(same line), or would it be very diffrent from what i have code?

Comment: You could use the same strategy